# How do I add a Table to a DataStore in Roblox Lua?

Tags: lua, roblox

GOAL: Make an Inventory system for Hats that saves So when you Buy a hat it adds it to your inventory.

What I have Currently:  Right Now I have a IntValue that is added to the player(not character) when they join. This IntValue is named "CurrentHat" and is set to the value of the players last saved hat they were wearing. After this it waits until Character loads to add that hat using CurrentHat's value to the players head by getting it from ServerStorage. Then if CurrentHat's value ever changes it connects it to add player hat function and connects it to the datastore. Below is the portion of the code where the data is added to the game and where I think the inventory data should be added to the game. All the commented out stuff is what I already tried(which failed).

```lua
function playeradded(player)
    print("hello")
    player:LoadCharacter()
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("IntValue")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    local hat = Instance.new("StringValue")
    hat.Name = ("CurrentHat")
    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue")
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Parent = leaderstats
    leaderstats.Parent = player
    hat.Parent = player
    hat.Value = ds2:GetAsync(player.UserId) or math.floor(math.random(0,1))
    --table.insert(hattable, hat.Value)
--  ds3:SetAsync(player.UserId,hat.Value)
    --for index,value in pairs (hattable) do
   -- ds3:UpdateAsync(index, function() return value end)
    --end
    --print(hattable[1])
    --print(ds3)
    local playerHat = hat.value
    hat.Changed:connect(function()
    ds2:SetAsync(player.UserId,hat.Value)
    --ds3:SetAsync(player.UserId,table.insert(hat.Value))
    --print(ds3)
    end)
    coins.Value = ds1:GetAsync(player.UserId) or 0
    ds1:SetAsync(player.UserId,coins.Value)
```

A good example of what I would like to do is the popular Roblox game SwordBurst's Inventory system except with only clothing.

I would like to be able to call on the players datastore and if the hat is included in the datastore then show it in their inventory to allow them to put it on. If anyone could help me that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save tables inside of `:SetAsync()` but you can inside of `:UpdateAsync()` so if you just do the following it should work:

```lua
local clothing = {"Hat1","Shirt1","etc"}

local datastore = game:GetService("DataStoreService"):GetDataStore("Clothing")

datastore:UpdateAsync("A_key",function()
    return clothing
end)
```

These variables are just examples. Please change some things accordingly